# The telerik text box couldn't display latin character after export pdf

Tags: asp.net, pdf, telerik, report, persian

My report include Persian/English character. I configured the telerik text box by Localizing Reports and everything was OK in report viewer. however, when I exported the report in PDF format the English character replaced with boxes.

I used the font that called `Nazanin`. If I changed the font to `Times New Roman` the problem solved, however, I need the `Nazanin` font for Persian character.

I read the Design Considerations for PDF Rendering and applied it. I also read Reporting PDF export of RTL languages, Export to PDF (Arabic / Persian Language) problem and Report Localization / Globalization Problem in telerik forum.
In the [Report Localization / Globalization Problem](http://www.telerik.com/forums/report-localization-globalization-problem#0WMqr5bFvEmBT697tcopXA), Stef (one of the forum's Admin) refer to [PDF Device Information Settings](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/device-information-settings-pdf), so I configured the web.config for 'Full Font Embedding` using Telerik Reporting Configuration Section and Extensions Element, however, my problem hasn't been solved yet.

I used the `HtmlTextBox` instead of `TextBox` in telerik reporting too, but my problem didn't solve.

Any helps, appreciated.

Comment: Open the `Nazanin` font in a font editor app. You will see that it has no English glyph in it. That's why ` the English characters are replaced with boxes`. If your PDF producing library doesn't have a font fallback mechanism, it won't be able to fix this problem. Dirty solution: Add the missing glyphs yourself to the font.

Comment: Thanks.  Which does PDF library have a font fallback mechanism? Can I add this mechanism to my project by a plugin or so on?

Comment: It's a web application. How will I add the missing glyphs to the font? Did you mean on server font?

Comment: iTextSharp has a font fallback mechanism. You need to use its `iTextSharp.text.pdf.FontSelector` class or else, use a complete font which has all of the glyphs.

Comment: Thanks VahidN. I'd like to integrate iTextsharp with telerik report viewer. I read these links :[Export gridview to PDF using itextsharp](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/styling-and-formatting-reports/details/exporting-a-report-to-pdf-programmatically), [Exporting a report to PDF programmatically](http://www.telerik.com/forums/export-gridview-to-pdf-using-itextsharp). However, I understood that I won't to integrate them, maybe. Is there any ways to integrate them?